# show a "confirmation" tab after HTTP post submit MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement as below. my form is having

tab1, tab2 , tab3, tab4 and tab5 (confirmation tab). tab4 having agree & submit button.
after click on submit button (http post, not ajax) when transaction is success tab5 should appear. how/where can i call below javascript based on the controller transaction success/fail?  please help.

[image]

below one is tab html

```html
<li class="invisible"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Confirmation " id="confirmation"><b>Confirmation</b></a></li>

<input type="submit" id="btnSummary" class="btn btn-primary" value="Agree and Submit" />
```

```js
  function Confirmation() {
        $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
        $("ul.nav li").removeClass('invisible').addClass('disabledTab');
        $("#navButtons").hide();
      }
```

Thanks,
Surya.

Comment: added Issucess property in model, after submit making success = true; then accessing IsSucess in jquery as below                                                                            below   ......................................                                                                             var onsuccess = "@Model.IsSuccess";
       
        if (onsuccess == "True") {
        
            $("ul.nav li").removeClass('invisible').addClass('disabledTab');
       }

Answer (score 0):

added Issucess property to model, after submit if transaction is good making IsSuccess = true; then accessing IsSucess in jquery as below below

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
 
   var onsuccess = "@Model.IsSuccess";
      //  alert(onsuccess);

        if (onsuccess == "True") {
        $("ul.nav li").removeClass('active');

            $("ul.nav li").removeClass('invisible').addClass('disabledTab');

           $('#Confirmation').find('a').trigger('click');
        }

    });
```